# Can't activate the expo manifest tools on Visual Studio Code

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

So I am currently trying to learn React and code on Visual Studio. Now, I am getting errors saying:

`Oops, it looks like we couldn't activate the Expo manifest tools: Unable to perform cache refresh for C:\Users\Jasun\AppData\Local\Expo\schema-43.0.0.json: Error: certificate has expired.`

Does anyone have any ideas?

Current versions are:

- git version 2.34.1.windows.1
- node version 17.2.0
- expo version 5.0.0
- Visual Studio Version 1.63.0
- yarn version 1.22.17

Answer (score 1):

reinstall doesn't help for now...

here is the workaround before they fix the issue - ["Certificate has expired" when activating the Expo schema](https://github.com/expo/vscode-expo/issues/87)

You may try the workaround derived from the issue description

```
> expo init temp-proj --template expo-template-blank@44
> cd temp-proj
> expo doctor
```

Once `expo doctor` executed, the `schema-44.0.0.json` appear in `%AppData%\Local\Expo\schema-44.0.0.json`

then you can delete the `temp-proj`...

Answer (score 1):

Warning: Problem validating app.json: Unable to perform cache refresh for ***C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Expo***schema-44.0.0.json: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 34.132.55.135:443.

1. Find schema-xx-x-x.json in C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\caches
2. or search with everything app in your PC
3. Paste on C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Expo\

Tadaaa Work

Answer (score 0):

updating your expo cli will fix the issue

npm install -g expo-cli

then check the new version
expo --version
OR
use this [link](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/2399) description

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  The problem occurs because the file schema-43.0.0.json is missing from the directory.

I fixed it by copying one of the other schemas and renaming it to the missing one.